# Laravel 6.x GuzzleHttp streaming in controller, stream not closed if request is aborted by user

Tags: php, laravel, server, guzzle, server-sent-events

I am using GuzzleHttp to call a streaming endpoint (Application-A) in another application (Application-B) of mine to stream statuses of a job through to a client - all works fine except that when the client closes the connection to Application-A, it keeps streaming the data from Application-B (as this client keeps sending keep-alive messages so keep the connection open). The whole streaming is built-up in a way that it's compatible with Server Sent Events and Application-A functions like a backend-for-frontend for the Client Application.

Below is the code for function inside Application-A for handling this:

```
    public function __invoke(Request $request): \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
    {
        $action = $request->route()->getAction();
        $method = $request->getMethod();

        // Step 01: Gather input from request
        $input = $request->all();
        // Step 02: Build request to CDN
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => getDomainEnv('CDN_HOST'),
            'http_errors' => false
        ]);

        $type = $this->getMediaType();
        $cdnReq = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
            'POST',
            "/generate/$type",
            [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ],
            json_encode($input)
        );
        $this->beforeRequest($cdnReq);
        // Step 03: Send request to cdn
        $response = $client->send($cdnReq);
        $body = $response->getBody();
        $contents = $body->getContents();
        $result = json_decode($contents);
        // Step 04: Check if response should be handled sync or async
        $sync = ($method === 'GET' || Arr::get($action, 'forceSync', false)) && Arr::get($action, 'async', false) === false;
        $finished = optional($result)->value->state === 'Job:Finished';

        if ($finished) return $this->onMediaResponse($result);

        // Sync
        if ($sync === true) {
            // Step 05: Start listening to the feed received from the cdn
            // Step 05a: Get channel from response
            $channel = optional($result)->value->channel;
            // Step 05b: Create url based on feed channel
            $url = getDomainEnv('CDN_HOST') . "/feed/$channel";
            // Step 05c: create request
            $feedReq = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
                'GET',
                $url,
                []
            );
            // Step 05d: send request
            $streamedResponse = $client->send($feedReq, ['stream' => true]);
            // Step 05e: get body
            $this->streamedBody = $streamedResponse->getBody();
            // Step 06: Wait until state === finished
            $buffer = "";
            while (!$this->streamedBody->eof() && !connection_aborted()) {
                Log::info(
                    "Connection info: ",
                    [
                        'aborted' => connection_aborted(),
                        'status' => connection_status()
                    ]
                ); // This log message
                while (!$this->streamedBody->eof() && !connection_aborted()) {
                    $buffer .= $this->streamedBody->read(getDomainEnv('FEED_PROXY_BYTES_READ', 16));
                    if ($pos = strpos($buffer, "\n\n") !== false) break;
                    if (connection_aborted()) break;
                }
                if (connection_aborted()) break;
                $message = substr($buffer, 0, $pos + 2);
                $buffer = substr($buffer, $pos + 2);

                Log::info('Received message: ' . $message); // This log message

                if (empty($message) || strlen($message <= 5) || substr($message, 0, 5) !== "data:") continue;

                $data = json_decode(substr($message, 6));

                if (optional($data)->state === 'Job:Finished') break;
                if (connection_aborted()) break;
            }
            // Step 07: Get resource from CDN
            dd($channel, $url, $data);
            // Step 08: Parse resource
            // Step 09: Prepare response for client
            // Step 10: Send response to client
        }
        // Async
        else {
            // Step 05: Get channel from response
            $channel = optional($result)->value->channel;
            // Step 06: Create url based on feed channel
            $url = route('feed.proxy', [
                'channel' => $channel
            ]) . "?target=" . getDomainEnv('CDN_HOST') . "/feed/$channel";
            // Step 07: Create response for client with feed channel
            dd($channel, $url);
            // Step 08: Send response to client
        }
    }
```

Below is the code for creating the feed inside Application-B, this is based on a Redis Pub/Sub pattern, so it receives data from Redis (which comes from the Job) and sends it through as server sent event to the client:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, string $channel)
    {
        $clientId = Str::uuid();
        Log::info("$clientId | Client started listening to feed channel: $channel");
        return response()->stream(function () use ($channel, $clientId) {
            Log::info("$clientId | Started streaming response back to client");
            $this->sendServerSideEventMessage([
                ['retry', 1000]
            ]);
            Log::info("$clientId | Initialized stream");

            Loop::run(function () use ($channel, $clientId) {
                Log::info("$clientId | Starting keep-alive loop");
                Loop::repeat($msInterval = 1000, function () use ($clientId) {
                    // Log::info("$clientId | Sending keep-alive!");
                    $this->sendServerSideEventMessage([
                        ['keep-alive', true]
                    ]);
                });

                $subscriber = new Subscriber(Config::fromUri(
                    config('database.redis.default.uri')
                ));

                $channel = config('database.redis.options.prefix') . $channel;

                Log::info("$clientId | Subscribing to the redis channel: $channel");
                $subscription = yield $subscriber->subscribe($channel);
                Log::info("$clientId | Subscribed to the redis channel: $channel");

                while (yield $subscription->advance()) {
                    $message = $subscription->getCurrent();
                    Log::info("$clientId | Received message from redis, passing it on to the client! => $message");
                    $this->sendServerSideEventMessage($message);
                }
            });
        }, 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream',
            'X-Accel-Buffering' => 'no',
            'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        ]);
    }
```

So the main issue is, when the client requesting the endpoint on Application-A disconnects, I keep seeing data being logged into the Laravel log file (See first code piece, the logs are marked with comments. So I assume the stream is being kept active.

Is there anyway to close it automatically when the user disconnects/aborts the request?

The second issue is that I try to parse the Server-Sent-Events messages from the stream, which end at each `\n\n` but it seems it doesn't work as I get really weird lines in my log, it almost seems that there are extra new-lines added or something, still need to test this though, see:

```
[2020-07-27 15:51:53] local.INFO: Received message: 

k  
[2020-07-27 15:51:53] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:51:54] local.INFO: Received message: eep  
[2020-07-27 15:51:54] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:51:55] local.INFO: Received message: -al  
[2020-07-27 15:51:55] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:51:56] local.INFO: Received message: ive  
[2020-07-27 15:51:56] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:51:57] local.INFO: Received message: : 1  
[2020-07-27 15:51:57] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:51:58] local.INFO: Received message: 

k  
[2020-07-27 15:51:58] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:52:00] local.INFO: Received message: eep  
[2020-07-27 15:52:00] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:52:01] local.INFO: Received message: -al  
[2020-07-27 15:52:01] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:52:02] local.INFO: Received message: ive  
[2020-07-27 15:52:02] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:52:03] local.INFO: Received message: : 1  
[2020-07-27 15:52:03] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:52:04] local.INFO: Received message: 

d  
[2020-07-27 15:52:04] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:52:05] local.INFO: Received message: ata  
[2020-07-27 15:52:05] local.INFO: Connection info:  {"aborted":0,"status":0} 
[2020-07-27 15:52:06] local.INFO: Received message: : {
```

Comment: did you get any solution I am facing the same issue.